# Feature detector for rotation and translation invariance?

Tags: opencv

I've got two very similar images, however they are usually rotated and slightly translated. The scale is pretty much the same. I've experimented with SIFT,SURF,ORB and AKAZE. And akaze turned out to be the best in computing the homography. OpenCV's implementation of akaze is slow on cpu (core i9 10 core) *[I've also built OpenCV 4.0 with AVX2, MKL and TBB, which should give the most optimal performance]*. I'd like to know if there is any simpler and faster way in doing this? I want to rotate and shift the inference test image according to the model image. Ideally I want to run this under 20-30ms time for 400x400 resolution.

So far I've used this pipeline: resize images -> feature detector -> matching (bruteforce,flann etc.) -> filter out points uing lowe's rule -> compute homography -> warp affine on inference test image.

I'm attaching sample images of model and test.

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have a GPU? You could use CUDA with ORB to do this, the accuracy may not be the same though

Comment: Yes I did use cuda ORB, and the results were really unacceptable.

Comment: I think at this point you would need to post your code, it maybe worth posting on http://answers.opencv.org/questions/ where you can get specialist help with this.

Comment: There are strong edges. What about MSER ?

Comment: Don't really know much about MSER, would it be fast? If yes, could you share some code or article on it? @YvesDaoust

Comment: I'm pretty sure Fast and ORB will work for this image. Did you try playing with the parameters or did you just try the defaults?

Comment: I made use for such task of the homography feature: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography

Comment: @RickM. Yes I did tweak the parameters for akaze and orb but not surf. I read that orb and akaze are the most rotation invariant detectors.

Comment: @planetmaker That is basically what I'm doing with other detectors, Sift cannot handle 360 degree rotations.

Comment: @RickM.: it's in OpenCV. I have no idea about the behavior on your particular image and I have no idea what you call fast.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've edited the question, it has to run under 20ms for 400x400 image. I'll implement it on opencv c++ provided i can refer something.

Comment: By FAST I meant, [FAST Algorithm for Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html)

Comment: @RickM. ORB uses fast for feature detection.

Comment: @RakshithGb Sure, but not just that.