# Use OpenCV's OpenCL feature detector

Tags: opencv

How to use OpenCL based feature detector? According to the source code ([here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.0.0/modules/features2d/src/opencl)) there is opencl version of AKAZE,FAST and ORB. I want to know how to use them in C++ ?

I tried importing `#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>` and then I also set `cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);` and for sanity check I did `cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()`. Doing these I can confirm I've built OpenCV with OpenCL support.

That being said I tried converting all `cv::Mat` to `cv::UMat`. Now the program crashes at `detector->detectAndCompute(umat, cv::noArray(), kp1, des1);`. I'm using AKAZE.

The error on the console is:

> OpenCV(4.0.0-dev) Error: Requested object was not found (could not open directory: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv) in glob_rec, file e:\cv4.0\opencv\modules\core\src\glob.cpp, line 267

The callstack error says :

> - _err    "could not open directory: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv" const
>     std::basic_string,std::allocator
>
>   > &

I've initialised it like this:

```
detector = cv::AKAZE::create();
detector->setThreshold(akaze_thresh);
```

Is this is the right way to use OpenCL version of AKAZE? If yes, how do I fix the error? If not, how do I use OpenCL version of AKAZE?

Comment: I am not sure if OpenCV has OpenCL support for AKAZE, they do have support for it using CUDA but this might have changed in 4.0. Did you try using ORB or FAST instead?

Comment: @RickM. Could you confirm if cuda support is still available for akaze? Or which is the last version of opencv is cuda akaze available? I haven't tried ORB and FAST, I'm not achieving the desired results with those 2 on CPU itself.

Comment: Try reading through [this Git repository](https://github.com/pablofdezalc/akaze)

Comment: What do you mean by _I'm not achieving the desired results with those 2 on CPU itself_? What are your desired results? Speed?

Comment: @RickM. Speed and accuracy. With AKAZE I’m getting 100+ matches, with ORB I’m barely getting 5+ matches and FAST is also more or less the same as ORB. Since akaze turned out be this good I wanted a faster version of it. It’s taking about 70ms for detection and matching on a core i9. I want to bring it down as low as possible.

Comment: Well, you could try tuning the parameters of ORB/FAST if the less number of matches is the primary issue. May be even adding filtering prior to matching to increase the matches. I am pretty sure that ORB/FAST are _really fast_. If you still don't get the desired results, the link to the repository I mentioned above has very fast implementations for AKAZE. Otherwise, try OpenCL with SURF, I am sure that it is supported.

Comment: @RickM. Yes I am aware of their speed, however I wasn't sure what to tweak to improve those matches. Tweaking it randomly din't help, the number of matches remained the same. Also my dataset changes, I cannot keep tweaking for each new dataset. AKAZE just works without any tweaking. Yes I will look into those implementations. Thanks.

Comment: By tweaking I meant changing the _EdgeThreshold_, _NLevels_ and [so on](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html). I was working on a similar project in the past where I needed speed, as much as possible, and accuracy (as we all do). I prepared a dataset, downsampled the images (to decrease the number of computations) and run ORB with different values to the parameters to find the best.

Comment: I did. I just changed edge threshold, nfeatures, patch size and fast threshold. I'm particularly failing to tune it for the image dataset of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703319/feature-detector-for-rotation-and-translation-invariance?noredirect=1#comment94265564_53703319) category.

Comment: And? Did it change the number/quality of the matches? Looking at the images, ORB should work fine (try unsharp mask before). May be MSER is better.

Comment: @RickM. I’m using the CUDA version of ORB now which is running between 20-30ms on GTX 1080 Ti after tweaking those said parameters. However the results are amazing for coins that have a clean metal, still fails for coins made out of poor metal like the above link. I will try to preprocess and see if it yields better results for that category. But this will again add overhead. I’m not really sure on how to use MSER to get rotation and scaling.

Comment: Well 20-30 ms is pretty neat I guess. Did you try using _only_ FAST with some parameter tweaking? In my experience it was **way** faster, and should be as the name suggests

Comment: @RickM. yes but FAST is just a detector, ORB is using oriented version of FAST, which in my case is more important. Using just FAST with BRIEF or BRISK description will surely result in poor accuracies but greater speeds. I'm not sure if that combination can handle 360 degree rotations.

Comment: Well if you use FAST, follow it with a descriptor and use [RANSAC](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) it should work fine. It did in my case where I was also concerned with orientations

Comment: What descriptor did you use ?

Comment: In my case, I think I used ORB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that for some reason the OpenCL cache folder wasn't getting generated (It should be here - `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv`). I created another project and ran a simple OpenCL program:

```
UMat m(100,100,CV_8UC3, Scalar(100,200,0));
UMat r;
GaussianBlur(m,r,Size(5,5),0);
```

This generated the required cache folder, I'm  now able to run the OpenCL version of AKAZE. Just to be clear for people who are referring this, OpenCL version of AKAZE is not fully implemented as of `OpenCV 4.0.0-dev`. Only some parts of the algorithm is running on OpenCL and hence the performance is more or less the same compared to original OpenCV AKAZE, the detection is still running on single thread.

There is a cuda verion available [here](https://github.com/donlk/cuda_akaze). And a highly multithreaded version available [here](https://github.com/h2suzuki/fast_akaze), which can run at 60 fps on 8 threads. Both these versions are built for `OpenCV 3.0.0` and should work with newer releases with small changes.